# CSS: Put first half of childs in left grid column

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

I've got a menu with 2 columns and I want the first half to float into the left column and the second half into the right one.

```css
nav ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4,auto);
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
        grid-column: 1;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(n+5){
        grid-column: 2;
    }
  
  /*
    
 This would be very annoying if there were
 more than just 4 elements that need to be
 put somewhere else manually.
  
    nav ul li:nth-child(5){
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(6){
        grid-row: 2;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(7){
        grid-row: 3;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(8){
        grid-row: 4;
    }*/
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Three</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Four</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Five</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Six</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Seven</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Eight</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I've come up with the following code which would solve the problem if it worked. Which isn't the case obviously.

```
nav ul li:nth-child(n+5){
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: calc(n-5);
}
```

How to do this correctly? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is `grid-auto-flow: column;`, it will place the next item at the top of the next column after it reaches the end of your repeat.

```css
nav ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Three</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Four</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Five</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Six</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Seven</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Eight</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Never heard of this rule  Maybe I'm just bad at googling the stuff I need  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

add `grid-auto-flow: column` in `nav ul`, and delete `grid-column: 1` and `grid-column: 2` rules.

```css
nav ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(4,auto);
        grid-auto-flow: column;
    }
    
    /*nav ul li:nth-child(-n+4) {
        grid-column: 1;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(n+5){
        grid-column: 2;
    }*/
  
  /*
    
 This would be very annoying if there were
 more than just 4 elements that need to be
 put somewhere else manually.
  
    nav ul li:nth-child(5){
        grid-row: 1;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(6){
        grid-row: 2;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(7){
        grid-row: 3;
    }
    
    nav ul li:nth-child(8){
        grid-row: 4;
    }*/
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Two</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Three</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Four</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Five</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Six</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Seven</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Eight</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you and @JHeth!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **flexbox**.

```css
nav {
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link">One</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">Two</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="nav-link">five</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav-link">six</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```